# React Router Dom components rendering in App.js, but not as separate component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, url-routing, react-router-dom

I'm in the process of trying to figure out how React Router Dom works, and have run into a problem that I am not even sure how to figure out.

If, within App.js, I have this snippet, then everything renders and navigates between the sections, just fine.

```
        <Switch>
            <Route path='/login-user' component={UserLoginForm} />
            <Route path='/login-database' component={LoginDatabaseSelect} />
            <Route path='/login-project' component={LoginProjectSelect} />
            <Redirect path='/' exact to='/login-user' />
        </Switch>
```

However, that is not the proper way, and I am trying to instead do this:
Create a different component that is referenced for this.

```
        <Switch>
            <Route path='/login' component={LoginSequence} />
            <Redirect path='/' exact to='/login' />
        </Switch>
```

And in LoginSequence the code is:

```
    import React from 'react';
    import { Route, Redirect, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
    import UserLoginForm from "./LoginSequence/loginUserPass";
    import LoginDatabaseSelect from "./LoginSequence/loginDatabaseSelect";
    import LoginProjectSelect from "./LoginSequence/loginProjectSelect";
    
    
    class LoginSequence extends React.Component {
        render () {
            console.log('Login Sequence')
            return (
                <div>
                    <h1>Login Sequence</h1>
                        <Route path='/login-user' component={UserLoginForm} />
                        <Route path='/login-database' component={LoginDatabaseSelect} />
                        <Route path='/login-project' component={LoginProjectSelect} />
                        <Redirect path='/login' exact to='/login-database' />
                </div>
            )
        }
    }

export default LoginSequence;
```

however, this component, does not even seem to be called as the console.log does not output anything to console. Meaning that nothing is rendering, and it is not getting called.

Can someone point me in the right direction as to why this isn't working?

Edit: I fixed up the From and changed it to Path in the snippet of code where LoginSequence is called, since it had no effect, but path seems to be the normal way of doing it.

Comment: @SoufianeBoutahlil it did not :( not sure what the differences between from and path are in context of redirect, but everything was still redirecting in both cases, just when calling LoginSequence component, it does not actually render anything, but links to proper pages it should be in.

Answer (score 2):

Change from to path in Redirect.

```js
 <Switch>
   <Route path='/login' component={LoginSequence} />
   <Redirect path='/' exact to='/login' />
 </Switch>
```

Comment: did not seem to have any effect. I get the redirects to the proper pages (such as /login-user), however, the component parts are not rendering if called through LoginSequence.

The console.log message for 'Login Sequence' (within LoginSequence component) does not trigger either, still.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use Redirect use Route and call in the component you want to render

```
 <Switch>
        <Route path='/login-user' component={UserLoginForm} />
        <Route path='/login-database' component={LoginDatabaseSelect} />
        <Route path='/login-project' component={LoginProjectSelect} />
        <Route path='/' exact component={login-user} />
    </Switch>
```

Comment: I see that there is a login-user component, what does that contain? My understanding is that it has to be something defined and imported.

Answer (score 0):

After talking to a couple of people, and seeing a few more examples, something became a bit more clear that solved the issue.

Within App.js:

```
        <Switch>
            <Route path='/login' component={LoginSequence} />
            <Redirect path='/' exact to='/login' />
        </Switch>
```

And the LoginSequence component within LoginScreen.js:

```
class LoginSequence extends React.Component {
    render () {
        console.log('Login Sequence')
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>Login Sequence</h1>
                    <Route path='/login/user' component={UserLoginForm} />
                    <Route path='/login/database' component={LoginDatabaseSelect} />
                    <Route path='/login/project' component={LoginProjectSelect} />
                    <Redirect path='/login' exact to='/login/user' />
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

What I noticed, is that the 'root' for referencing changes every time, so, once I redirect to `/login` to be `loginsequence`, the new area that components are looked for is within `/login`. Thus `/login/<user/database/project>` has to be the new path, rather than just `/<user/database/project>`, as it seems to look for the references of that, within App.js and can't find them, thus not rendering. Seems like RRD follows a 'tree' structure of a sort, and every time you want to nest it, you have to follow the structure of

```
/<path of component containing further routes>/<route of component referenced in component>
```